# Is it possible to dynamically inset a mesh (using a modifier)?

Tags: modifiers

I would like to know if there is a way to dynamically (with modifiers) inset a mesh.
Thanks !
[image]

Comment: Is the double ring the same mesh as the rest or are these 2 objects ? The smooth modifier might help here